# jquery-ui is not working in angular 4 project

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jquery-ui.accordion functionality in an Angular 4 Project but is not working, the .accordion functionality is not working on my template.

package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
 "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
 "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.2",
 "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
}
```

angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "assets/js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"
      ],
```

my-current-products.component.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui'

...

ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    $("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
  }
```

my-current-products.component.html

```
<div class="brand summary__home" id="accordion">
   <h3 *ngIf="localPayment">
     <p> some text </p>
   </h3>
</div>
```

**Edit**

The accordion does not appear when use angular 4 directives.

Any help?

Comment: Did you inspect it? Any errors? Are you getting proper rendering but the div is not collapsing?

Comment: Hi, please check my eidt, the problem appears when use angular 4 directives in the template.